# Converting this recursive formula to a function (if possible)

Tags: functions, recursion

Anyone know how to convert this to a function?

$\begin{align}
a(n)&=a(n-2)(\frac{n}{n-1}) \\
a(1)&=1
\end{align}$

I understand maybe this can’t be converted to a function because it can’t return anything for even values of n, but maybe a function that has returns the same values for odd values of $n$?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for some context it’s a project I’ve been working on. This is the formula that I’ve come up with that returns the expected difference between heads and tails (as a positive number) by flipping a coin n times.

Comment: Small remark: recursion is already a legal way to define a function, even if you succeed in writing it with $n!$ you just moved the recursion into notation.

Answer (score 0):

Writing out a few terms, we can see a pattern. For example,

$$a_7=\frac{7}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot1$$

In general, 
$$a_n = \frac{n!!}{(n-1)!!}\tag{1}$$
where $!!$ represents the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). This can be proved by induction.

You can also write equation $(1)$ in terms of only normal factorials. For odd $n$,
$$n\ odd:\ a_n=\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}((\frac{n-1}{2})!)^2}$$
If you want to also define $a_n$ for even $n$ according to equation $(1)$, then it becomes
$$n\ even:\ a_n=\frac{(\frac{n-2}{2})!\ (\frac{n}{2})!\ 2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$